# Xtext - how to make cross-references by file name?

Tags: java, xtext, cross-reference

I want to cross-reference in XText not by using some attribute in the other file, instead by file metadata (the file name).

```
import: "string_msg/msg/StringMessage"

inputs:
    name: testString
    type: types.string_msg.StringMessage   # this is the cross-reference
    description: "Here goes some type of description or the other"
```

The language "string_msg/msg/StringMessage" belongs to only contains attribute information, not the type name. I have to derive the type name from the filename, but ideally make the model objects of the referenced file available.

How do I do this? All examples I have seen so far have referenced other EObjects by their name attribute.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can adapt the `IQualifiedNameProvider` and use the `EObject`s `eResource` and the resources `URI` to calculate the name.

```
package org.xtext.example.mydsl10;

import org.eclipse.emf.common.util.URI;
import org.eclipse.xtext.naming.DefaultDeclarativeQualifiedNameProvider;
import org.eclipse.xtext.naming.QualifiedName;
import org.xtext.example.mydsl10.myDsl.Greeting;

public class MyDslNameProvider extends DefaultDeclarativeQualifiedNameProvider {

    public QualifiedName qualifiedName(Greeting g) {
        URI uri = g.eResource().getURI();
        // this is your job 
        String simpleName = uri.trimFileExtension().lastSegment();
        return QualifiedName.create(simpleName, g.getName());
    }

}
```

dont forget to bind

```
class MyDslRuntimeModule extends AbstractMyDslRuntimeModule {

    override bindIQualifiedNameProvider() {
        MyDslNameProvider
    }

}
```

Comment: The answer would be better with a little more detail, since the documentation of Xtext is not really straightforward to read - I assume the `IQualifiedNameProvider` has to be implemented in the project of the referencing grammar, not the referenced?

Comment: adapted with a very sijmple example

Comment: if you want to change only a referening grammar you need to adapt scoping and change names. (cretate `AliasedEObjectDescription`s)

Comment: Ok thanks, that did something. I get a bunch of stuff proposed and filenames that are not what I expect, but I can work from here I think.